# convert view from oracle to mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, view

Following is the oracle query,

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view1 AS
 SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2
       FROM (select * FROM table1 asap, table2 pids where asap.parentid= pids.parentid) t1,
            (select * from table1 r_asap,table3 ids where r_asap.id=ids.id) t2
        WHERE
             t1.col2=t2.col2 and
             (t2.col3 <>t1.col3 OR
              t2.col4<>t1.col4 OR
       t2.col5 <>t1.col5 )
       order by t1.col1
```

I need to convert that to MYSQL view.. can any one help me in this

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried to conver to mysql query, but not mysql view.. following is the query for mysql.. I need view `select t1.col1,t1.col2 from (select asap.* FROM table1 asap, table2 pids where asap.parentid= pids.parentid) t1,
 (select r_asap.* from table1 r_asap,table3 ids where r_asap.id=ids.id) t2
 WHERE
             t1.col2=t2.col2 and
             (t2.col3 <>t1.col3 OR
              t2.col4<>t1.col4 OR
       t2.col5 <>t1.col5 )
       order by t1.col1`

Comment: I'm confused in t1 and t2 comparision in where condition. how to do for mysql

Comment: I have posted and answer  hope is useful

Comment: @scaisEdge Hi, posted?

Comment: @phanikiran   . posted  now  .. (strange ... seesm posted but ....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be mysql compatible but overall use explicit join  (and for me is more readable)

and due the fact that mysql don'tallow the use of subquery in view you must first create a view for the subselect and on this build the final view

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_sub1 AS
    SELECT col1, col2 
    FROM table1 asap 
    INNER JOIN  table2 pids on asap.parentid= pids.parentid;

    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_sub2 AS
    SELECT c2l2
    FROM table1 r_asap
    INNER JOIN table3 ids on  r_asap.id=ids.id ;

    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view1 AS
    SELECT view_sub1.col1,view_sub1.col2
    FROM view_sub1
    INNER JOIN view_sub2 on view_sub1.col2=view_sub2.col2  
    WHERE view_sub2.col3 <>view_sub1.col3 
    OR    view_sub2.col4<>view_sub1.col4
    OR    view_sub2.col5 <>view_sub1.col5;
```

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, error SQL Error (1349): View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: alternatively I did the same way.. i.e., created separate tables then used those tables...But, I'm trying to do in one query.. which is not possible... with two reference in where condition.. Any way thanks for your answer...and accepted it...